# Remove last occurrence of a string in a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that is of nature

- RTT(50)
- RTT(A)(50)
- RTT(A)(B)(C)(50)

What I want to is to remove the last () occurrence from the string. That is if the string is - RTT(50), then I want RTT only returned. If it is RTT(A)(50), I want RTT(A) returned etc.

How do I achieve this? I currently use a substring method that takes out any occurrence of the () regardless. I thought of using:

```
Regex.Matches(node.Text, "( )").Count
```

To count the number of occurrences so I did something like below.

```
 if(Regex.Matches(node.Text, "( )").Count > 1)
      //value = node.Text.Remove(Regex.//Substring(1, node.Text.IndexOf(" ("));
 else
     value = node.Text.Substring(0, node.Text.IndexOf(" ("));
```

The else part will do what I want. However, how to remove the last occurrence in the if part is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does what you need - returns the last index of a char or string.

If you're sure that every string will have at least one set of parentheses:

```
var result = node.Text.Substring(0, node.Text.LastIndexOf("("));
```

Otherwise, you could test the result of `LastIndexOf`:

```
var lastParenSet = node.Text.LastIndexOf("(");

var result =
    node.Text.Substring(0, lastParenSet > -1 ? lastParenSet : node.Text.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks. However, i would like to what happened if the string doesnt have an instance of parenthesis?

Answer (score 13):

This should do what you want :

```
your_string = your_string.Remove(your_string.LastIndexOf(string_to_remove));
```

It's that simple.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different options to consider.

#### LastIndexOf

Get the last index of the `(` character and take the substring up to that index. The downside of this approach is an additional last index check for `)` would be needed to ensure that the format is correct and that it's a pair with the closing parenthesis occurring after the opening parenthesis (I did not perform this check in the code below).

```
var index = input.LastIndexOf('(');
if (index >= 0)
{
    var result = input.Substring(0, index);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

#### Regex with RegexOptions.RightToLeft

By using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` we can grab the last index of a pair of parentheses.

```
var pattern = @"\(.+?\)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
if (match.Success)
{
    var result = input.Substring(0, match.Index);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

#### Regex depending on numeric format

If you're always expecting the final parentheses to have numeric content, similar to your example values where `(50)` is getting removed, we can use a pattern that matches any numbers inside parentheses.

```
var patternNumeric = @"\(\d+\)";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, patternNumeric, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. You can easily achieve like this:

string a=RTT(50);

string res=a.substring (0,a.LastIndexOf("("))

Answer (score 1):

As an extention:

```
namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string ReplaceLastOf(this string str, string fromStr, string toStr)
        {
            int lastIndexOf = str.LastIndexOf(fromStr);
            if (lastIndexOf < 0)
                return str;

            string leading = str.Substring(0, lastIndexOf);
            int charsToEnd = str.Length - (lastIndexOf + fromStr.Length);
            string trailing = str.Substring(lastIndexOf+fromStr.Length, charsToEnd);

            return leading + toStr + trailing;
        }
   }
}
```

Use:

```
string myFavColor = "My favourite color is blue";
string newFavColor = myFavColor.ReplaceLastOf("blue", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

try something a function this:

```
public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string source, string find, string replace)
{
    int place = source.LastIndexOf(find);
    return source.Remove(place, find.Length).Insert(place, replace);
}
```

It will remove the last occurrence of a string string and replace to another one, and use:

```
string result = ReplaceLastOccurrence(value, "(", string.Empty);
```

In this case, you find `(` string inside the `value` string, and replace the `(` to a `string.Empty`. It also could be used to replace to another information.