# How do I remove only the url from text and Ignore other url in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to remove only the last instance of the URL in a string in c#.

Example String: `"sample text  http://www.url1.com sample text https://www.url2.com sample text http://www.url3.com"`

I would like to remove only `"http://url3.com"` , and keep the other URL in the string.

Will some combination of string functions and regex will help achieve the same? I tried regex, but it removes all instances of the URL.

Edit : This involves matching the last URL (which is random each time ) and removing i.

@GaurangDave answer worked well

Comment: you can replace the desired text as empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove last occurrence of a string in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556020/remove-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-string)

Comment: It depends on whether you are replacing a pattern or a constant string? As your question stands the answer would be:

 string result = input.Replace("http://www.url3.com", ""); 

Maybe you could show the code that you tried?

Comment: since the URL is random each time, we cannot implement the input.replace.

Comment: @CoolBots Why you just didn't try help the person answering the question?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes because the question is a duplicate; this exact question has been asked, and has a good answer, in the link posted in my very first comment (generated by a duplicate question flag).

Comment: @CoolBots: I think the linked question and its accepted answer is a bit different where the answer suggests the use of `lastIndexOf` of `(` because there the string to be removed is like a fixed string like `(sometext)`. But this post asks to remove the last URL and a URL can be of various forms where it may start with either `http` or `ftp` or `file` or may be some other. Although I know the question only mentions the sample data for `http` but in situations like I said above, a regex solution would be more powerful and easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: @PrincelySamuel: Check my answer and my C# code samples, what you are seeking can be much easily and simply done using one line code using `Regex.Replace`. Just pass the appropriate regex and replace the matched data with empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used generic Regex pattern to find url from text. You can change according to your need. This example works for your scenario. It will remove last url from string.

```
string txt = "sample text http://www.url1.com sample" +
             "text https://www.url2.com sample text " +
             "http://www.url3.com";

var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)");

txt = txt.Replace(matches[matches.Count - 1].Value, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the last URL using this regex,

```
http\S*$
```

And replace it with empty string.

**[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/DZXLC9/1/)**

If optionally there can be space after last URL, you can optionally match it using this regex,

```
http\S*\s*$
```

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/DZXLC9/2)**

In case you want to support more protocols, you can have alternation in regex specifying different protocols like this,

```
(?:file|ftp|http)\S*\s*$
```

**[Demo3](https://regex101.com/r/DZXLC9/3)**

C# Sample codes,

```
string str = @"sample text http://www.url1.com sample text https://www.url2.com sample text http://www.url3.com";
string replacedStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?:file|ftp|http)\S*\s*$", "");
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + replacedStr);
```

Prints,

```
Result: sample text http://www.url1.com sample text https://www.url2.com sample text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex solution that also works if you have extra text after the last URL:

```
string input = "sample text http://www.url1.com " +
               "sample text https://www.url2.com " +
               "sample text http://www.url3.com " +
               "extra text";
int pos = input.LastIndexOf("http://", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
string lastURL = 
    new string(input.Substring(pos).TakeWhile(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
string output = input.Substring(0, pos) + input.Substring(pos + lastURL.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Last URL: " + lastURL);
Console.WriteLine("Cleaned text: " + output);
```

**Output:**

```
Last URL: http://www.url3.com
Cleaned text: sample text http://www.url1.com sample text https://www.url2.com sample text  extra text
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do now :)