# How to extract character before last pattern using regex alteryx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, alteryx

i would like to extract text before last item within brackets

|Groupname|

|---------|

|Agile Transformation (FGH)|

|Innovation Lab|

from the raw data below using regex

|Groupname|

|---------|

|Agile Transformation (FGH) (10000)|

|Innovation Lab (10001)|

Comment: See solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556020/remove-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

By using multiline regex and negative lookahead mechanisms, you can extract very last section title and its associated content.

For instance, with:

```
\|(?<title>[^|\n]+)\|(?!(.|\n)*\|.*\|(.|\n)*)\n?(?<content>(?:.|\n)+)\Z
```

(try and look detailed explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/pTDlUl/1)

Cheers